Group actions on functions induced by group actions on their domain
In Exercise 1.30 of Ryan O'Donnell's Analysis of Boolean Functions is written

Permutations $\pi \in S_n$ act on strings $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$ in the natural way: $(x^{\pi})_i=x_{\pi(i)}$. They also act on functions $f:\{-1,1\}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ via $f^{\pi}(x)=f(x^{\pi})$ for all $x\in\{-1,1\}^n$.

The notation seems to me to suggest that the actions on $x$ and on $f$ are both right actions. However, this seems to me not to work, since one would have $f^{\pi\sigma}(x)=f(x^{\pi\sigma})=f((x^{\pi})^{\sigma})=f^{\sigma}(x^{\pi})=(f^{\sigma})^{\pi}(x)=f^{\sigma\pi}(x)$, which would not in general equal $f^{\pi\sigma}(x)$.
If instead I suppose that the action on $x$ is a left action, and if I denote that by ${}^{\pi}x$, so that ${}^{\pi\sigma}x={}^{\pi}({}^{\sigma}x)$, and if instead I define $f^{\pi}(x)=f({}^{\pi}x)$, then I have $f^{\pi\sigma}(x)=f({}^{\pi\sigma}x)=f({}^{\pi}({}^{\sigma}x))=f^{\pi}({}^{\sigma}x)=(f^{\pi})^{\sigma}(x)$, then I have a right action on $f$, as hoped.
Note: It seems that if one treats $x$ in turn as a function from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into $\{-1,1\}$, so that $f$ is a function of a function then the two apparent reversals of handedness cancel out, giving $f^{\pi\sigma}(x)=f({}^{\pi\sigma}x)=f((x_{1^{\pi\sigma}},\ldots,x_{n^{\pi\sigma}}))$. Using a more common notation for elements of $S_n$ and suppressing a pair of parentheses for clarity, this last term becomes $f(x_{\sigma\pi(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma\pi(n)})$. However, here I think I am somehow confusing domains of actions with domains of functions acted upon. I imagine that to untangle that mess one would want to adopt the more abstract definition of an action, as a homomorphism from a group into the symmetric group on a set.

Am I getting something quite wrong?
Am I right that the left- and right- superscripts are an existing convention for left- and right- actions, respectively?
Am I right that when actions on sets of functions with a common domain are induced by actions on that domain, then the handedness of the two actions must differ?
What is going on with the 3-level situation following "Note", above?


In general, left action on variable results in right action on functions. Most people prefer to work with left actions, hence, define action on functions by $f(g^{-1}x)$. This keeps one in the realm of left actions.

Thank you ! I think I understand. Do you mean that for $g$ in the group and $f$ a function, $(gf)(x)=f(xg)=f(g^{-1}x)$ ?

Right...........
